How to maintain synchronization between distributed python processes?
I have a number of workstations that run long processes containing sequences like this:
x = wait_while_current_is_set
y = read_voltage
z = z + y

The workstations must maintain synchronization with a central unit that runs processes like  this:
x = set_current
y = wait_while_voltage_is_read
z = z + y

It's actually implemented like this on both client and server:
x = set_current
y = read_current
z = z + y

--with "set_current" and "read_current" implemented as library functions from the client and server libraries.
How do I synchronize parallel distributed asynchronous processes in python?

Your question isn’t very easy to understand but the answer is probably multiprocessing.barrier or multiprocessing.event.

To maintain synchronization between distributed processes in Python, consider the following steps: First, for operations like "set_current" and "read_current", make sure that they are implemented reliably and consistently on both the client and server sides. Next, messaging mechanisms can be used for communication and synchronization between processes. For example, use a message queuing framework such as RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ. When a process completes a key operation, such as "set_current", it sends a specific message to the message queue to notify other processes. Then, distributed locks are used to control access to critical resources. For example, using Redis to implement distributed locks ensures that only one process can perform certain critical synchronization operations at any given time. In addition, you can set up monitoring and logging mechanisms to detect and diagnose problems that occur during synchronization. Finally, the entire system is fully tested, including under different loads and abnormal conditions, to ensure the stability and reliability of the synchronization mechanism. In short, synchronization between distributed Python processes can be achieved well with reliable communication, effective locking mechanisms, sound monitoring, and adequate testing.
